# Calling static methods from a class defined in another project requires libraries added for both projects

Tags: java

I have two projects in my NetBeans window

```
MyProject
  Tester.java
Utilities
  Utils.java
```

The `Utils.java` file contains a number of static methods written by others that we can re-use. Recently I added a new set of static methods to `Utils.java` that uses new external jar's. I added the libraries to the `Utilities` project via `Properties --> Libraries --> Add Library`

I then proceeded to call these methods from within `Tester.java` but received `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exceptions for the classes that were defined in those external libraries. This does not occur when I call the methods from within the `Utilities` project.

I solved the problem by adding the required libraries to the `MyProject` project as well, but is there a reason why I have to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the external libraries in your MyProject as well because it is transitively dependent on those libraries. You are getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError because the required classes were available for the Utilities during the compile time to build the jar but those classes are missing at the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple: `Utils.class` relies on the classes from the library to work. So if you don't have the classes of the library in the classpath, `Utils.class` can't work. Just like just having an accelerator is not sufficient to make a car move. Without the car engine, the accelerator can't work. The fact that you, as a driver, don't mess with the engine directly, but only through the accelerator, doesn't mean the engine is not necessary. (sorry for this car analogy, but hopefully it makes things clearer).